# What does 'sharp' mean as it relates to being physical?

Tags: meaning

Someone told me "You are very sharp, though I will leave it up to you to decide if I mean mentally or physically".

What does *sharp* mean in the 'physical' context?

Comment: Was is a native speaker who told you that? (I'm asking because in German, scharf (sharp) also means hot, so it might be a false friend.)

Comment: If not, meaning (8) seems possible: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sharp?show=0&t=1410382864

Comment: More likely to be (4) keen in spirit or action.  This is a better match with the mental keen, (3).

Comment: I've never heard of anyone describing a *person* as "physically sharp". A *knife* or *needle* or *corner*, of course, can be described as physically sharp, but I don't see how that could be extended, even figuratively, to a person.

Comment: @painfulenglish nope, not a native speaker. An European, though I am not sure about the country.

Comment: I think whoever told you that was trying to be more clever than their vocabulary would justify. Most likely he meant he'd leave it to you to decide whether he meant *sharp = **sharp-witted***  or *sharp = **sharp-tongued, sour, churlish***. The difference being a matter of *intellect* as against *emotion, social character*, not a "physical" attribute.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think the answer lies in what @FumbleFingers says. Thanks for responses, guys.

Comment: @Sumit: Because we're only interacting in text here, I never stopped to think of the possibility given by painfulenglish's second link. Perhaps your admirer/detractor thinks of you as a ***sharp dresser*** (smart in appearance, not brainpower).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Our only interaction is through a forum, and we never met in person. Hence, I would tilt towards what you said earlier.

Comment: Probably the only physical reference: Sharp: Terminating in an edge or a point: a sharp nose.

Comment: @Josh61: Over a lifetime I've heard several people facetiously ask if they can borrow a pencil sharpener before going out shopping in the January sales or similar (to sharpen up their elbows, so they can "chisel" their way to the counter and score a bargain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physically, sharp usually refers to your clothing (e.g., a coordinated outfit) or personal grooming (e.g., carefully combed hair).

Ref: Slang definitions & phrases for sharp (via Dictionary.com)

sharp (adj)

1. stylish; of the latest and most sophisticated sort: He wore bow ties and sharp suits (1940+ Jive talk)

Also found in a line from a famous ZZ Top song: "'Cause every girl crazy 'bout a sharp dressed man."

Comment: Could you please quote a reference, so that the OP can verify this meaning? Thank you. Perhaps your answer would benefit if you provided a bit more detail :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Mari-Lou A. I added one definition reference and one popular culture example.